How to model Cubic shape on Circular shape (with SubD-modifier)
I'm making this "button" shape. And in my opinion there are no N-gons here. However I have massive glitching/shading issues when applying SubD-modifier3 on the object. When I make the control loops go around the whole object the circular shape stays as an octagon.
How should the topology look like for this kind of shape so one would get rid of the shading issues after applying the SubD-modifier?
Thanks!



You have a massive N-Gon there. Just use the knife tool for now to convert this N-Gon of 6 vertices into 4 Quads. I have a template on how to achieve that easily in the Picture.


Here you have n-gon with six sides. Try to get rid of it, also more even topology sometimes helps as well with sub-d.
